# Windows OS support in Azure VS AWS any list

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, azure-vm-templates

Is there anyway I can get to know what are all the windows OS support available in Azure when compared with AWS.

I wanted to create VM in azure with win7, win8 and  win10 OS versions is it possible?
And also creating EC2 with same OS's is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the list for AWS:

https://aws.amazon.com/windows/resources/amis/

And the I think this is right for Azure:

https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps?filters=virtual-machine-images%3Bwindows%3Bmicrosoft&page=1

There are obviously going to be custom ones that other people create and put into AWS marketplace, but by looks of it these are all the generic ones.